# Application crash randomly and shows WebKit Legacy issue

Tags: webkit

My Objective-C application crashes randomly and shows a WebKit Legacy issue there in a stack trace. Can you please identify the problem?

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18ecc8150 objc_msgSend + 16
1  WebKitLegacy                   0x195fe0808 <redacted> + 132
2  CoreFoundation                 0x190256d54 <redacted> + 404
3  CoreFoundation                 0x190152d4c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
4  CoreFoundation                 0x190258e80 <redacted> + 144
5  CoreFoundation                 0x19014e2c4 <redacted> + 292
6  WebCore                        0x194e28be8 <redacted> + 108
7  CoreFoundation                 0x19020142c <redacted> + 24
8  CoreFoundation                 0x190200d04 <redacted> + 388
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1901fe9a8 <redacted> + 744
10 CoreFoundation                 0x19012eda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
11 UIFoundation                   0x19632c134 <redacted> + 1764
12 Foundation                     0x190d464cc <redacted> + 340
13 CoreFoundation                 0x19020142c <redacted> + 24
14 CoreFoundation                 0x190200d04 <redacted> + 388
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1901fe9a8 <redacted> + 744
16 CoreFoundation                 0x19012eda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
17 GraphicsServices               0x191b98074 GSEventRunModal + 100
18 UIKit                          0x1963e9058 UIApplicationMain + 208
19 NewsHog                        0x1000d71a0 main (main.m:16)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x18f13d59c <redacted> + 4
```

Comment: Maybe you should show the actual code so we don't have to randomly guess at the problem.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, answer your own question.